# Why am i getting PermissionError

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

This is an inception v3 model bird recognition code. After training the epoch while predicting image I copied the image path from my pc and pasted it. When i run the cell it is giving me a Permission Error. How to resolve this issue?

```
predict_image('C:\\Users\\a2z\\Downloads\\archives\\train\\AMERICAN COOT',model)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_2300\3977302100.py in <module>
----> 1 predict_image('C:\\Users\\a2z\\Downloads\\archives\\train\\AMERICAN COOT',model)

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_2300\1012446031.py in predict_image(filename, model)
      1 def predict_image(filename, model):
----> 2     img_ = image.load_img(filename, target_size=(228, 228))
      3     img_array = image.img_to_array(img_)
      4     img_processed = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)
      5     img_processed /= 255.

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\image_utils.py in load_img(path, grayscale, color_mode, target_size, interpolation, keep_aspect_ratio)
    420         if isinstance(path, pathlib.Path):
    421             path = str(path.resolve())
--> 422         with open(path, "rb") as f:
    423             img = pil_image.open(io.BytesIO(f.read()))
    424     else:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\a2z\\Downloads\\archives\\train\\AMERICAN COOT'
```

For this predict image code i was excepting the model to predict this image but, it is giving me a permission error.
I wonder is it because i have placed my image in C drive if this is the issue then i only have one drive that is C drive. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: What does deep learning have anything to do with your question?

Comment: Given that there is no extension, I suspect that you're trying to open a folder

Comment: Is the file open somehow already? Like are you viewing it or anything like that? maybe try add f.close()?